# Docker: hiding the content of bash script file when running a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, vite

I am building a docker image for a React front-end application that needs to be deployed within a server owned by a client.

So, I have created a Dockerfile that contains two stages (build and production).Also, I am using Vite to build the web app.:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN npm run build

ENV NODE_ENV=production

USER node 

FROM node:18-alpine as production

WORKDIR /app/build

ENV APPLICATION_PORT=3001
EXPOSE ${APPLICATION_PORT}

COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/dist ./dist
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/package*.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/docker-entrypoint.sh ./
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/.env ./

RUN npm install serve -g
RUN npm install @import-meta-env/cli --save-dev

RUN chmod +x ./docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Within the `docker-entrypoint.sh`, I am doing some validation to make sure that the environment variables are set:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x 

function validateEnvVariables {
    echo "validating the front-end env variables."
    if [[ -z "${API_BASE_URL}" ]]; then 
        echo "The API_BASE_URL is not set."
        exit 1
    fi

    if [[ -z "${MATERIAL_UI_KEY}" ]]; then
        echo "The MATERIAL_UI_KEY is not set."
        exit 1
    fi
}

validateEnvVariables

echo "Setting the variables"
npx import-meta-env --example .env

echo "Start the server"
npm run serve
```

With that, I am able to create the Image. However, When I am creating a container with the built image, the code of `docker-entrypoint.sh` is always displayed in the terminal (with a + sign beside each line of code).
Also, I am able to see the environment variables that are passed from the docker container cmd line:

`docker run -e API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000 -e MATERIAL_UI_KEY=SOME_KEY -p 3001:3001 --name front-end someImageName`

Terminal Display:

```
+ validateEnvVariables
+ echo 'validating the front-end env variables.'
+ '[[' -z http://localhost:3000 ]]
+ '[[' -z SOME_KEY ]]
+ echo 'Setting the variables'
+ npx import-meta-env --example .env
validating the front-end env variables.
Setting the variables
Start the server
+ echo 'Start the server'
+ npm run serve

> consentement-municipal@0.0.0 serve
> serve -n -s dist -p  $APPLICATION_PORT

INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:3001
```

So, is there a way to tell docker not to display the code base of the script and only print the values with the keyword `echo`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Docker. If you don't want your script to generate trace output, don't `set -x`.

Comment: Iarsks thanks you so much. Yes the generate output comes from the -x